# Only Execute if the query is select statement from c#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to write a function which receives a `Sql-Query` as parameter. I would like to execute it only if it is select statement and return data. In other case, if parameter contains delete, update or truncate, the function should return null.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Best solution is to *not* write such a function but use either an ORM like EF or a micro-ORM like Dapper.

Comment: Don't try this without parsing the statement (which is not an easy task). What you are trying to do opens a huge security hole in your system. It is better not to do it. If you must have it, ask your DBA to create an account with read-only access to the DB, and run queries using that account's connection. This way DB would reject any update that you may send its way.

Comment: ADO.NET's ExecuteReader also works fine with INSERT/DELETE, it will simply return nothing if there are no results

Comment: Could you use a login which allows only READ access to all tables and doesn't allow you to execute stored procs or WRITE / DELETE?

Comment: Besides, an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE *can* return results if it has an OUTPUT clause, eg to return a new identity value when inserting without having to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() and risk retrieving the wrong value, and works for batches too

Comment: I think you will get better response if you are able to provide, sample inputs(one to be executed and one to be ignored). And one more thing, the mentioned  *function* is a `C#` function or an `SQL` function? if it is `SQL` then why it is tagged to `C#`

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible idea on every level; unless you're writing something like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), you should **never** accept SQL from the outside world. In addition to allowing unchecked read to anything, it can almost certainly be abused to do *just about anything else*. For example:

```
exec ('del' + 'ete from SomeData')
```

doesn't contain `delete`. Then you get into an arms race with attackers, and before you know it they've run `xp_cmdshell` without an `exec` (the `exec` is optional for an implicit call) and you no longer own the server at all.

There *are* ways to parse a SQL operation, but it *almost certainly* isn't worth it. SQL is complex and nuanced and most parsers won't be up-to-date. If you're writing an ad-hoc query API for a reporting tool, maybe consider a separate query DSL that is simpler to parse, allowing you to check the syntax and then *construct* safe parameterized SQL once you've checked everything against an allowed list.

Or better: don't expose ad-hoc query *at all*; it is rarely needed, outside of reporting systems. If this is just for your convenience allowing you to push SQL into views / client-side instead of having to  write a route per operation: then you're doing it very wrong.